# Stack snippets external file validation needs to be fixed

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

I went to edit a question that was linking to Google Fonts with `http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,300,500,600,700` and when clicking the "Add an external library" the snippet editor came back with:

> Sorry, but that resource is invalid. Resources must begin with http://
> or https:// and allowed extensions are: .css, .js

Obviously the link is valid, so can you please update the validation to **not** reject these links with querystrings?

Comment: As a workaround, you can just add some other css file (even a bogus one like `https://.css` will do) and replace the URL in the generated html with the one you want to use, as it's only the "Add an external library" button that has the validation. (or of course just type the `link` element in yourself)

Comment: You could also probably just add `#.css` to the end of that url... Thought that validation is probably overkill